# Using tikzlibrary{graphs} how can I create a loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphs

Here is a minimum example that does not work

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{graph}{
        1 -> 2;
        3 -> 3;
        };
    \end{graph}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I'm trying to get 3 to loop to itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just tell `tikz` that you want a loop:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \graph{
        1 -> 2;
        3 ->[loop below] 3;
     };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

If just write `3 -> [loop] 3;` then the loop goes over node 1.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. And sorry, I did look through the manual but somehow never managed to find that!

Comment: @Henry No need to apologise as it doesn't seem to be in the manual:)